# Tree Shaking Lodash with Webpack 3.8.1

Tags: lodash, webpack-3, tree-shaking

- Lodash@4.17.4
- Webpack@3.8.1
- babel@7
- babel-plugin-lodash@3.3.2

  I use named imports when it comes to Lodash. I've configured
  @babel/preset-env with 'modules' set to false to prevent transpilation to
  Common JS and
  use 'lodash' as a plugin in the 'babel-loader' config.
  Despite all this, I realised my chunk has the entire Lodash, and is
  significantly bloating it up. What can I do to enable lodash from getting
  pruned? I am neither importing the entire library in my code , nor am I
  using chaining.

Answer (score -1):

I maintain a library of (much) smaller versions of lodash functions. It is written using a modern build chain, so tree shaking should happen easily. You could check whether it has everything you need: [`micro-dash`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/micro-dash).

Comment: Got one question about micro-dash, does it support chaining methods like lodash 'chain' does? If yes, then how can we do it?

Comment: @asdasd No, it does not. It is only loose functions (which makes it very tree-shakeable)